# Matlab2016b saves figures in different resolution that I set

Tags: matlab

I encountered a wierd issue after I upgrade my Matlab from 2015a to 2016b, the following codes just perform differently:

```
imshow(image,'border','tight','initialmagnification','fit');
set(gcf,'Position',[0,0,1280,720]);
axis normal;
f=getframe(gcf);
```

The image I was using is 720*1280 in size. The output variable 'f' was still 720*1280 in MATLAB2015a while turns out to be 900*1600 in MATLAB2016b. Is there anybody meet with this problem? Any comment is welcomed.

Comment: Is 900*1600 your screen resolution?

Comment: @bushmills no my screen is 1920*1080